# Speeding up temp table joins in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, join, temp-tables

I have 2 temp tables #temp1 and #temp. Both have a key and date columns. Both have around 25k rows. And I'm left joining them on the basis of the key and date which are unique on all rows. It's taking around 4 minutes for this join to complete. Is there any way to speed it up or any alternative methods?

Comment: can you post a repro script we can play with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can create indexes on temporary tables as on any other tables.

Comment: This is a good idea - as well as specifying a primary key on your temp tables.

Comment: I am not sure if having an index on 25k will give you any performance benefit. If I recall there seems to be a threshold before SQL Server will start to use an index. Otherwise it is going to table scans because it is quick than traversing and index each time. I would bench mark the two.

Comment: The key thing you get from the indexes is the data is now "pre-sorted". Done properly, the optimizer should be able to use a merge join or a nested loop instead of a hash match.

Comment: i still question the actual needs of the temp tables.

Answer (score 3):

If your join of `25k` tables takes `4` minutes, there's something wrong with it.

Most probably you put a wrong `JOIN` condition which leads to a cartesian join (or something close to it), which results in `25k * 25k = 625M` records returned.

This can take `4` minutes indeed if not more, but I don't think it was what you wanted.

Probably you have `DISTINCT` / `GROUP BY` clauses in your query, which makes the query to return correct resultset but in a non-optimal way.

Could you please post your query so that I can tell the exact reason?

Answer (score 1):

I have a suspicion that your whole query might want looking at. There may be another way to skin this particular rabbit.

Could you leave some more detail?

Comment: I'm not known for my query writing skills. But that indexing advice seems to have worked. I created a clustered index on the joining columns of one temp table and its returning results quite quickly now.

Answer (score 1):

depending on what you're doing you could probably avoid the temp tables altogether and have a set-based solution (which will run a lot quicker and scale better), but that's hard to know without any idea of what your query is.